# in embedded application, no of sectors has gone up. how to find out where it has increased

Tags: c++, embedded, keil, firmware

In the embedded manufacturing firmware, if the number of sectors is increased, then what might be the reason for it and how to find out where it has increased.

Using:

- Keil for debugging.
- Eclipse for browsing.

Working on sam4c microcontroller.

Comment: What do you mean by "sectors"? We need more context.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a Keil question than a C++ question.

It has been a while since I used Keil, but I remember that one of the output files from a compilation is a file where it lists where it placed all your functions and variables in memory (sorry, I can't remember the file name). That should let you see what takes up space in the two different versions, and figure out where it has changed.

I tried to do a quick search to find that filename, but instead I just found this:
http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/uv4/uv4_dg_memmap.htm
Maybe you can use that...